# Patching a bash function

Tags: bash, python, bash-functions, virtualenv

I have a shell function (ok, it's the `deactivate()` function defined by a Python virtualenv), and I would like to patch it by inserting some statements before or after it's executed. My goal is to have a new `deactivate()` function that does what the old one did, plus a bit more. Is there a way to accomplish this?

The original function is dynamically defined from various places (the various virtualenvs), so modifying it at every source is not an attractive option.

Comment: what about writing new function and calling deactivate from it? it should word in every venv you have

Comment: That would work, but I would prefer to be able to type "deactivate" like I'm used to. The point of the question is not to have to change the name. A solution that copies the current definition to a new name would be fine.

Comment: (Plus, in general, there may be other scripts that call the original name, and we want its behavior to be patched.)

Answer (score 1):

You either could ceate a deactivate alias (if that is enough) which has higher priority than a function. In that you could run a command before, but is not easy to run after.

```
alias deactivate='before; deactivate'
```

Or simply (much better) create a function with a simpler name:

```
deact(){ [[ $somevar == true ]] && deactivate
         [[ $othervar == admin ]] && sudo deactivate
       }
```

Or anything you want to implement. Yes that will only run where defined. It is **not a replacement for the word `deactivate` nor it works for other users.

The only way to do that is to create an executable program called `deactivate`, but that has lower priority than aliases and functions. Both will need to be un-defined.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. In _this_ case, an alias will work pretty well, also for post-processing, because the function `deactivate` does not take any arguments. But since `deactivate` manipulates the environment and is different for each virtualenv, an executable is not going to cut it. (Neither is a script combined with an alias for sourcing, as far as I can see.)

Answer (score 1):

If your shell is `bash`,`zsh` or `ksh93` you can take advantage of the `typeset -f` builtin, which shows the source of a function:

```
# usage patch_func funcname before after
function patch_func {
        typeset nl=$'\n' lb={ src=`typeset -f "$1"` before=$2 after=$3
        src="${src/$lb/$lb$nl    $before$nl}"
        src="${src%\}*}$nl    $after$nl}"
        eval "$src"
}
```

Example:

```
$ deactivate(){ echo -n "{$0}"; for i; do echo -n " {$i}"; done; echo; }
$ patch_func deactivate 'echo before' 'echo after'
$ typeset -f deactivate
deactivate ()
{
    echo before;
    echo -n "{$0}";
    for i in "$@";
    do
        echo -n " {$i}";
    done;
    echo;
    echo after
}
```

This is of course quite fragile.

Answer (score 0):

Although this answer does not directly apply to `virtualenv` usage - how about using `virtualenvwrapper`? It's basically `virtualenv` on steroids, taking care of envs management. Once installed, you get a set of additional commands:

- `workon` lists all available environments when called without arguments, and activates the env when called with env name as agument, for example `workon myenv` activates the env `myenv`;
- `mkvirtualenv myenv` creates a new env `myenv`;
- `rmvirtualenv myenv` removes it.

But there's more - `virtualenvwrapper` defines a set of useful hooks where you can implement your own logic for envs customization, for example:

- `premkvirtualenv` is executed when an env is created, but not activated yet;
- `postmkvirtualenv` is executed when an env is created and activated;
- `preactivate` is executed when an env activation was triggered;
- `postactivate` is executed when an env was activated;
- `predeactivate` is executed when an env deactivation was triggered;
- `postdeactivate` is executed when an env was deactivated;

and many more. For example, I have a `postmkvirtualenv` hook that installs `ipython` in a new env:

```bash
$ cat $VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_HOOK_DIR/postmkvirtualenv
#!/bin/bash
# This hook is sourced after a new virtualenv is activated.

env=$(basename "$VIRTUAL_ENV")
logger -s -t "($env)" "installing ipython ..."
"$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin/pip" install ipython --quiet
```

To define additional logic for the env deactivation, you would thus have to write a custom bash script and place its contents to either `$VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_HOOK_DIR/predeactivate` (if you need to run your stuff while the env is still activated) or `$VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_HOOK_DIR/postdeactivate` (if you need the env to be deactivated to run the custom code).

For reference: [`virtualenvwrapper` docs](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).

For a complete list of hooks, refer to [Per-User Customization](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/scripts.html).